# Extract XPath for HTML code

Tags: php, html, xpath

I've this HTML code ....

```
.....
.....
.....
<div class="bloccoOspedale">
 <div id="nomeOspedale">
  <div class="datiOspedale">Pazienti in corso di visita: 2 di cui in O.B.I.: 0</div>
  <div class="datiOspedaleCodici">
   <div class="codBianco">Codice bianco:0</div>
   <div class="codVerde">Codice verde:1</div>
   <div class="codGiallo">Codice giallo:1</div>
   <div class="codRosso">Codice rosso:0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="datiOspedale">Pazienti in attesa di visita: 0</div>
 </div>
 <div class="bloccoOspedale">
  <div id="nomeOspedale">
   <div class="datiOspedale">Pazienti in corso di visita: 23 di cui in O.B.I.: 0</div>
  <div class="datiOspedaleCodici">
   <div class="codBianco">Codice bianco:1</div>
   <div class="codVerde">Codice verde:9</div>
   <div class="codGiallo">Codice giallo:11</div>
   <div class="codRosso">Codice rosso:2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="datiOspedale">Pazienti in attesa di visita: 10</div>
 </div>
 <div class="bloccoOspedale">
  <div id="nomeOspedale">
   <div class="datiOspedale">Pazienti in corso di visita: 16 di cui in O.B.I.: 2</div>
   <div class="datiOspedaleCodici">
    <div class="codBianco">Codice bianco:0</div>
    <div class="codVerde">Codice verde:9</div>
    <div class="codGiallo">Codice giallo:7</div>
    <div class="codRosso">Codice rosso:0</div>
   </div>
   <div class="datiOspedale">Pazienti in attesa di visita: 6</div>
  </div>    
.....
.....
.....
```

and I've to extract the string "**Codice bianco:0**" using XPath in PHP ... 
I've tried

```
//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[1]/text()
```

or

```
//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[@class="codBianco"]/text()
```

but nothing happens ....

What is the right XPath?

Thank you in advance ...

**UPDATE**

I've tried to use this PHP code sample ...

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $url = 'http://www.asl1.liguria.it/templateProntoSoccorso.asp';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $Number = $xpath->query('//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[@class="codBianco"]/text()');

    foreach( $Number as $node )
    {
      echo "Number: " .$node->nodeValue;
      echo '<br>';
      echo '<br>';
    }    
?>
```

... to make clearer what I need ..... the code runs with no errors but nothing is printed ...

Comment: open the page in chrome. open developer tools. find the element you need in source and click copy xpath. done

Comment: Exactly what I've done (using Firefox .....), but it doesn't work ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fragment of your XML, the following code...

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement ( $xml );
$text = $doc->xpath('//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[@class="codBianco"]/text()');
foreach ( $text as $t ) {
    echo $t.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Does in fact echo...

```
Codice bianco:0
Codice bianco:1
Codice bianco:0
```

Comment: #Nigel I've updated my original question with a little code sample that I use to test ..... It seems very similar to yours (you use SimpleXMLElement, I use   DOMXPath and it works for other case in the sampe "business case in my code, so I'd like  not to change...), but unfortunately my code print nothing. Suggestions?

Comment: I've just cut and paste your code and it gives me `Number: Codice bianco:0<br><br>Number: Codice bianco:1<br><br>Number: Codice bianco:0<br><br>`.  Can you put `echo "Loaded:".$dom->saveXML();` after your `loadHTML` line and check that you get some output.

Comment: That is exacty what I'd like to obtain!!! .... quite strange that in my case it does not work .... anyway now I know that my code is right .... Thanks!

Comment: Nigel ... if you can ... now my code works  (I simply restart my Ubuntu VM .....), BUT ..... if I use in my code complete xpath like `/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/text()` to extract a single text instead of `//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[@class="codBianco"]/text()` to extract all the occurences of "codBianco" class again nothing is printed ... thanks in advance

Comment: I've solved .... this is the right xpath to use `(//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[1]/text())[1]` to get the text of the first instance of the class "codBianco". NOTE the `[1]` at the end!